# ResourceNotFoundException - Trying to get icons based on String value

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-viewholder

i am using web service to get weather list from api.forecast.io. when i get the parameter string icon, i am parsing the string icon value from api and get the icon resource from class utility with viewholder

```
vh.icon.setImageResource(Utility.getIconfromWeatherCond(item.getIcon()));
```

this is method for *getIconfromWeatherCond*

```
public static int getIconfromWeatherCond (String icon) {
    if (icon=="clear-day") {
        return R.drawable.ic_clear;
    }
    else if (icon=="clear-night") {
        return R.drawable.ic_clear;
    }
    else if (icon=="rain") {
        return R.drawable.ic_rain;
    }
    else if (icon=="snow") {
        return R.drawable.ic_snow;

    }
    else if (icon=="sleet") {
        //hujan campur es
        return R.drawable.ic_snow;
    }
    else if (icon=="wind") {
        return R.drawable.ic_cloudy;
    }
    else if (icon=="fog") {
        return R.drawable.ic_fog;
    }
    else if (icon=="cloudy") {
        return R.drawable.ic_cloudy;
    }
    else if (icon=="partly-cloudy-day") {
        return R.drawable.ic_light_rain;
    }
    else if (icon=="partly-cloudy-night") {
        return R.drawable.ic_light_rain;
    }
    else if (icon=="hail") {
        return R.drawable.ic_snow;
    }
    else if (icon=="thunderstorm") {
        return R.drawable.ic_storm;
    }
    else if (icon=="tornado") {
        return R.drawable.ic_storm;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

but when iam trying to runing on my device i get error like this.
*android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0xffffffff*
what should i do??

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

Code your `getIconfromWeatherCond` method like this:

```
    public static int getIconfromWeatherCond (String icon) {

        switch (icon) {
        case "clear-day":
            return R.drawable.ic_clear;
        case "clear-night":
            return R.drawable.ic_clear;
        case "rain":
            return R.drawable.ic_rain;
        case "snow":
            return R.drawable.ic_snow;
        case "sleet":
            //hujan campur es
            return R.drawable.ic_snow;
        case "wind":
            return R.drawable.ic_cloudy;
        case "fog":
            return R.drawable.ic_fog;
        case "cloudy":
            return R.drawable.ic_cloudy;
        case "partly-cloudy-day":
            return R.drawable.ic_light_rain;
        case "partly-cloudy-night":
            return R.drawable.ic_light_rain;
        case "hail":
            return R.drawable.ic_snow;
        case "thunderstorm":
            return R.drawable.ic_storm;
        case "tornado":
            return R.drawable.ic_storm;
        default:
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

---

Check for "no icon" value:

```
  int resId = Utility.getIconfromWeatherCond(item.getIcon());
  if (resId != -1) {
      vh.icon.setImageResource(resId);
  } else {
      Log.d(TAG, "No image resource for icon: " + item.getIcon());
  }
```

Now your logcat will tell you what value you don't have, but knowing how these remote services work, I bet it's just going to be blank.

Comment: i got the data but the icon image didnt load from R.drawable.* :3. this is my Log.d "08-09 23:11:35.844 20206-20206/com.cahyo.wibowo.jalretrovit D/jajal: No image resource for icon: rain"

Comment: Oh dear god, I looked at your code and didn't even see it!  Basic Java: you can't use == to compare strings.  I am updating my answer.

Comment: Certainly a `HashMap<String, Integer>` would be better than a switch-case on strings?

Comment: I can think of three better ways, but let's ease cahyowhy into it, shall we?

Comment: thanks @krislarson its worked with switch case statement :)